# How to link to Spring Java Application with Dynamic Java Project containing Webservices

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I have made two project Let Say BankDao a java-spring application and other BankService a dynamic web project containing web services. I have made Jar of BankDao and added to the build path of BankService.
But the problem is that when I am calling the methods of BankDao , it is giving null pointer exception.But all the methods are working in BankDao project. I am unable to understand how can I configure these two application

**BankServiceImp ** in **BankService Project**

```
public class BankServiceImpl implements BankService {

public BigDecimal getAccountBalance(String accountNumber) {
    BalanceEnquiry balanceEnquiry= new BalanceEnquiry();
    return balanceEnquiry.getBalanceAmount(accountNumber);
}
```

**BalanceEnquiry** class in **BankDao Project**

```
public class BalanceEnquiry extends JdbcDaoSupport {

public BigDecimal getBalanceAmount(String accountNumber) {

    String sql = "Select balanceAmount from accountDetails where accountNumber=?";

    BigDecimal balanceAmount = (BigDecimal) getJdbcTemplate()
            .queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { accountNumber },
                    BigDecimal.class);

    return balanceAmount;
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dao.balanceenquiry.BalanceEnquiry.getBalanceAmount(BalanceEnquiry.java:13)
at com.bankops.impl.BanksServiceImpl.getAccountBalance(BankServiceImpl.java:20)
```

**Update:** Initially(During application loading) spring is creating beans for BankDao but later all the beans are getting null

Comment: paste the code + stacktrace.

Comment: It is giving null pointer beacuse getJdbctemplate() method not able to connect with database or we can say getJdbcTemplate = null

Comment: May I know the reaon for down vote

Comment: I have already shared. getJDBCTemplate is method of JDBCDAOSupport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem :-

*BalanceEnquiry balanceEnquiry= new BalanceEnquiry();*

You are creating the object of balance enquiry using new operator. Hence, this object is not spring bean and hence this object  is different from the bean being created.

Either you need to make your service as spring bean and inject dao in it by autowire or dependancy inject.
In spring 3.0 ,you can your service applicationContext aware to get bean.

In case , you don't want  to make service impl spring bean , then you need to get use application context to get bean.

```
ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletContext(); //any normal webapplication      code can be used to get servlet context

WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

BalanceEnquiry balanceEnquiry= (UserBean)wac.getBean("balanceEnquiry ");

Comment: if you decide to have spring in first project it will be more easier for you.

Comment: if you don't want to have spring imports in your non-spring web project , you can write factory class in spring project using Webapplication context to get your dao bean as dao instance. You just need to pass your servlet context in factory method

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned before problem is because BalanceEnquiry have not been instantiated properly (as spring bean) because of

```
BalanceEnquiry balanceEnquiry = new BalanceEnquiry();
```

Why it is not correct? Because simple instance of BalanceEnquiry class will be crated, without any spring-related objects (some jdbc objects in our case). There will be no errors because BalanceEnquiry is regular java class. 
To make it work BalanceEnquiry should be obtained like spring bean: by getting instance of it from spring context.

Try to do following:

In your BankDAO project (which runs on spring) create a class e.g. BankDAOGateway:

```
public class BankDAOGateway {
   private BalanceEnquiry;

   public BankDAOGateway() {
      GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
      ctx.load("classpath:app-context.xml");
      ctx.refresh();
      balanceEnquiry = ctx.getBean("balanceEnquiry", BalanceEnquiry.class);
   }

   public BalanceEnquiry getBalanceEnquiry() {
      return balanceEnquiry;
   }
}
```

Then instead of creating BalanceInquiry in your BankServiceImpl:

```
BankDAOGateway bankDaoGateway = new BankDAOGateway();
BalanceEnquiry balanceEnquiry = bankDaoGateway.getBalanceEnquiry();
```

In that case on bankDaoGateway construction step sprting context should instantiate properly and you will be able to get bankEnquiry with not null getJdbcTemplate();